# DynamoDB FilterExpression with NOT IN

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run a filter expression on a DynamoDB query (in a Node.JS environment), for one of the attributes not to be in a list of those attributes. I'm doing this:

```
documentClient.query( {
    TableName: 'event',
    IndexName: 'OrganisationTimestamp',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#ts BETWEEN :from AND :to',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#ts': 'Timestamp'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':to': to,
        ':from': from,
        ':ignoredUserIds': "1, 2, 3"
    },
    FilterExpression: 'not (userId in (:ignoredUserIds))'
  })
```

However I'm not having any luck here, and getting items back with the userId attribute within that range.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**`IN`** - can be used only if `userId` attribute is defined as DynamoDB **`LIST`** data type

> IN : Checks for matching elements in a list.
>
> AttributeValueList can
>   contain one or more AttributeValue elements of type String, Number, or
>   Binary. These attributes are compared against an existing attribute of
>   an item. If any elements of the input are equal to the item attribute,
>   the expression evaluates to true.

**Solution:**

Change the FilterExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues as mentioned below. It should work.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':to': to,
        ':from': from,
        ':userid1': "1",
        ':userid2': "2",
        ':userid3': "3"        
    },
FilterExpression: 'userId <> :userid1 and userId <> :userid2 and userId <> :userid3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `ignoredUserIds` as if it was a Macro...
you should do:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':to': to,
    ':from': from,
    ':id1': 1,
    ':id2': 2,
    ':id3': 3,
},
FilterExpression: 'not (userId in (:id1, :id2, id3))'
```

if you're only mapping numbers you should be able to do:

```
FilterExpression: 'not (userId in (1, 2, 3))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example code to exclude some of the items by id. NOT IN scan query -
My table have date_time, id, message columns.

```js
async fetchAllItemsByTimeRange(
  startTime: string,
  endTime: string,
  itemsExclude: string[] = [],
) {
  const expressionAttributeNames = {
    '#date_time': 'date_time',
  };
  const expressionAttributeValues = {
    ':startTime': {
      S: startTime,
    },
    ':endDateTime': {
      S: endTime,
    },
  };
  let filterExpression = '#date_time BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime';
  if (itemsExclude.length) {
    expressionAttributeNames['#id'] = 'id';

    const tnxIdStrArr: string[] = [];

    itemsExclude.forEach((tnxId) => {
      expressionAttributeValues[`item${tnxId}`] = {
        N: tnxId.toString(),
      };
      tnxIdStrArr.push(`:item${tnxId}`);
    });
    filterExpression += ` AND NOT(#id IN (${tnxIdStrArr.join(',')}))`;
  }

  const failedTransactionsParams = {
    ExpressionAttributeNames: expressionAttributeNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
    FilterExpression: filterExpression,
    TableName: PaybackBasePointFailedTransactionsTuple.TABLE_NAME,
    ProjectionExpression: 'id, date_time, message',
  };

  return await this.dynamoDb
    .scan(failedTransactionsParams)
    .promise();
}
```